# Passing binary data as arguments in bash

Tags: bash, character-encoding, parameters

I need to pass binary data to a bash program that accepts command line arguments. Is there a way to do this?

It's a program that accepts one argument:

```
script arg1
```

But instead of the string `arg1`, I'd like to pass some bytes that aren't good ASCII characters - in particular, the bytes `0x02`, `0xc5` and `0xd8`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
script "`printf "\x02\xc5\xd8"`"
script "`echo -e "\x02\xc5\xd8"`"
```

test:

```
# echo -n "`echo -e "\x02\xc5\xd8"`" | hexdump -C
00000000  02 c5 d8                                          |...|
```

Comment: I believe your test is equivalent to the simpler `echo -ne "\x02\xc5\xd8" | hexdump -C` :-)

Comment: Not quite... here I'm trying to simulate the actual call of `script`, by replacing it with `echo -n`

Answer (score 27):

Use the `$''` quote style:

```
script $'\x02\xc5\xd8'
```

Test:

```
printf $'\x02\xc5\xd8' | hexdump -C
00000000  02 c5 d8
```

Comment: `$''` is Bash mechanism for quoting [ANSI C like strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)

Answer (score 7):

Bash is not good at dealing with binary data. I would recommend using base64 to encode it, and then decode it inside of the script.

Edited to provide an example:

```
script "$(printf '\x02\xc5\xd8' | base64 -)"
```

Inside of the script:

```
var=$(base64 -d -i <<<"$1")
```

Comment: Agreed.  I haven't found any way to get bash to deal with zero bytes (\x00) in strings, and it tends to add/remove trailing newlines (\x0a) as it thinks best -- both are quite bad when dealing with arbitrary binary data.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ script "`printf "\x02\xc5\xd8"`"
```

Comment: you don't want bash to process the argument... `script "\`printf "\x02\xc5\xd8"\`"`

Comment: @yi_H Good point. Fix applied, which leads directly to your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Save your binary data to a file, then do:

```
script "`cat file`"
```

Comment: UUOC. How about script $(<file) or script "$(<file)" (Depending on whether or not you want word splitting to occur).

Comment: @Cam what are you doing inside of the script? What is your expected results?

Comment: @jordanm: isn't $(<file) an extension? It doesn't work with dash, at least. So I'm not sure this is useless.

Comment: It's a bash specific extension. This question is only tagged bash, so presumably he would have #!/bin/bash at the top of his script.